# How to set pixelOffset for info windows?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

For info windows, I'm aware of the `setContent` and `setPosition` functions.  Is there a `setPixelOffset`-like function which allows you to change the offset?  `setPixelOffset` doesn't exist as a function.

Comment: use `setOptions`

Comment: @geocodezip That works, thanks

Answer (score 7):

Simplest way is to use the setter (or `setOptions` to set multiple options at once):

```
infowindow.set("pixelOffset", new google.maps.Size(10,10));
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/358wnm9n/3/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50),
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, 0)
  });
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 9,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.4529192156, -116.22985867),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);

  map.addListener('click', function(e) {
    infowindow.setContent("<input type='button' value='change pixelOffset' id='btn' /><input id='xval' value='20' size='2' /><input id='yval' value='20'  size='2' />");
    infowindow.setPosition(e.latLng);
    infowindow.open(map);
    infowindow.addListener('domready', function() {
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('btn'), 'click', function() {
        var size = new google.maps.Size(parseInt(document.getElementById('xval').value), parseInt(document.getElementById('yval').value));
        console.log("size=" + size.toString());
        infowindow.set("pixelOffset", size);
        infowindow.open(map);
      })
    });
  });
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'click', {
    latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(43.4529192156, -116.22985867)
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

After the infoWindow initialization

```
 var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "Hello World",
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
    disableAutoPan: true,
    maxWidth: 300,
    pixelOffset:new google.maps.Size(215, 265)
    });
```

you could set the pixelOffset parameter using the setOptions. Hope this might help someone.

```
infoWindow.setOptions({
        pixelOffset:new google.maps.Size(215, 370)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `pixelOffset` option in the `InfoWindowOptions` object:

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(-30, 90),
  content: "Hello World",
  pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -10)
});
infoWindow.open(map);
```

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/info-window#InfoWindowOptions.pixelOffset)

Comment: That does **not** answer the question! OP is aware that there is a `pixelOffset` property. He is asking how he can change it. There is already a correct answer to this question. Why do you post that then?

Comment: The original question was quote "Is there any way to set pixelOffset for info windows?", which has several answers (constructor, `set`, `setOptions`). Also, my answer was posted *before* geocodezip's answer if you look at the timestamp. https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

Comment: My bad regarding the time you posted this. Still it's not what OP was asking for, if you read the question (and not only the title).